# How do I get a traceback of a HTTP500 from IIS running on Azure's "App Service" PaaS?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I've inherited an ASP.NET project with instructions to run it on Azure's App Service. I set up a pipeline to compile it (with `debug` in the `Configuration` param & `system.debug=true` of the compilation step), created a release to deploy it, but it doesn't run (returns a HTTP500.0 with error code 0x00000000). But try as I might, I can't get a proper traceback out of IIS.

I have tried:

- Turning off `CustomErrorMessages` in `Web.config`; this just shows IIS's "an error occurred and for security we're hiding the details" HTTP500 page.
- Viewing the live log feed in the "App Service Editor", then copy-pasting the html to view it (just gives generic error messages).
- Downloading the Application logs [as per Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files); they're just generic HTTP500 pages with no trace.
- Enabling "Application Insights" APM and viewing failures, but 0 failures are reported.

I'm stumped. **How do I get the App Service variant of IIS to show me a simple traceback?**

Comment: You can set get detailed error message from two ways. First is check event viewer for error message and error code. Second is setting `httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"`, not CustomErrorMessage.

Comment: @BruceZhang The second suggestion is the one I was looking for - how to configure IIS to show the full trace. Unfortunately that suggestion only shows a half trace of the EF libraries that were called, but not the full trace of the error line in my app's code. IIS unhelpfully suggests adding `<compilation debug="true">` to `<system.web>`, but of course I have already done this.

Comment: I came here hoping for an answer to exactly the same problem.  If someone here since solved it, please post the resolution.

Comment: @VeteranCoder I have posted a solution. It's not a very satisfactory one through.

Comment: @Escher, thank you.  I eventually figured that out on my own, but your answer will save time for other wayward seekers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application stack trace is available in the logs, which can be viewed in "Advanced tools" menu of the App Service, or alternatively can be downloaded as a zip file as described in [MSFT's instruction|](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files). The relevant file that shows the stack trace inside this zipfile is `eventlog.xml`.